# The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. error on checkout page magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. error on checkout page  Magento 2

Comment: run indexing command and try again

Answer (score -1):

This error comes from an exception given by this path vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php line 308
$product->load($productId);
if (!$product->getId()) {
throw new NoSuchEntityException(
__("The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again.")
);
}

Go to exception because it doesn't find the productId, if it's there first and it doesn't find it after, it must be a problem with an external module, try disabling it and reindexing and caching, you should solve it.